# What were the winning prestige classes?

Tags: prestige-class, dnd-3e, wizards-of-the-coast

Wizards of the Coast in Jan. 2001 sponsored a [prestige class contest](http://archive.wizards.com/dnd/article.asp?x=dnd/dx20010115f) on the company's messageboards, and, I assume, announced the results mid-April. Unlike the earlier [spellwriting contest](http://archive.wizards.com/dnd/article.asp?x=dnd/dx20010126b) that saw winners' spells published on the Wizards main site, winning prestige classes seem confined to the now-gone *Dungeons & Dragons Boards*.

Some contest entries are archived [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20010426082148/http://boards.wizards.com:80/dnd-bin/forumdisplay.cgi?action=topics&number=23&forum=-%20Prestige%20Class%20Contest!&DaysPrune=30&startpoint=0), but the first message in the subboard that I suspect contains the names of the winning prestige classes—much to my frustration—is *not* archived.

According to an [*ENWorld* thread](http://www.enworld.org/forum/showthread.php?70886-Are-there-any-good-quot-pole-armsman-quot-Prestige-Classes-out-there-(reach-weapons)) the prestige class [the longblades](https://web.archive.org/web/20010610024011/http://boards.wizards.com/dnd/Forum23/HTML/000057.html) won the contest, yet the entry was posted mid-March, about two weeks *after* the (supposed?) end-of-Feb. deadline. Further, the *Internet Archive* doesn't have an index for messages from that far back, having nothing before *late* March.

What prestige classes won the Jan. 2001 Wizard of the Coast-sponsored prestige class creation contest? Are these winning classes available elsewhere?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After some archive.org crawling, I came across [this post](https://web.archive.org/web/20010820142614/http://boards.wizards.com:80/cgi-bin/ultimatebb.cgi?ubb=get_topic&f=116&t=000441), a "Quick Links" to unofficial PrCs.  It lists the following as Contest Winners:

- [The Scarecrow](https://web.archive.org/web/20010610024923/http://boards.wizards.com:80/dnd/Forum23/HTML/000105.html)
- [Scarlet Squirrel](https://web.archive.org/web/20010610024646/http://boards.wizards.com:80/dnd/Forum23/HTML/000081.html)
- [Longblades](https://web.archive.org/web/20010610024011/http://boards.wizards.com:80/dnd/Forum23/HTML/000057.html)

Since the last entry is corroborated by your ENWorld link, the Wizards archive page specifies there were to be three winners, and discussion elsewhere in the thread mentions the "WizO" moderators' involvement, I believe these are your answers.