# All I really want are squirrels

Tags: dnd-3.5e, monsters, wild-shape, prestige-class

The fan-made prestige class [scarlet squirrel](https://web.archive.org/web/20010610024646/http://boards.wizards.com:80/dnd/Forum23/HTML/000081.html) (see also [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/112282/8610)) at level 3 gains the natural ability **weresquirrel** that, in part, says, "The character can polymorph into any known squirrel form recognized by the DM, in the same manner as a druid's" supernatural ability [wild shape](http://dndsrd.net/druid.html#druid-wild-shape).

While updating this prestige class for possible use in a *Dungeons & Dragons 3.5* campaign, I was struck by the dearth of official possible squirrel forms.

Actual squirrels seems to include only the **flying squirrel** (*Dragon* #327 87) and the traditional **squirrel** that originally appeared as a unique new creature (*Dragon* #280 60, 61) yet was updated by the *3.5* revision (*Dragon* #341 89) to have statistics identical to that of the rat (*MM* 278)—which is a little insulting but, honestly, understandable.

Squirrel-adjacent creatures seem to include only the **ratatosk** that's described as a "furry, humanoid-shaped creature [that] resembles a bipedal rodent [with] clawed hands, large eyes set in a squirrel-like head, and a long, luxuriant, furry tail [l]ike the flying squirrels…" (*Expedition to the Demonweb Pits* 110–11) and the **skiurid** that's described as "a shadow-born version of a squirrel, disturbingly familiar in appearance but undeniably malicious" (*Monster Manual IV* 126–7).

As the DM, I'd like to recognize more squirrels. To that end, in first party, licensed, and third-party products what other squirrels exist? That is, what creatures have the actual word *squirrel* in their names?

Further, in first party, licensed, and third-party products, what other squirrel-adjacent creatures exist? That is, what creatures are described as being squirrel-like? To be clear, like the above examples illustrate, I'm interested *only* in creatures that are *specifically* squirrel-like. For instance, even a chipmunklike [*sic*] creature isn't squirrel enough, so if a creature's description *doesn't* mention squirrels—even if such a creature *seems* like it *should be* squirrel-adjacent and even if such a creature does have a supercute name like the berrygobbler (*Silver Marches* 41)—, it just won't do.

As the prestige class scarlet squirrel is a 9-level class, an emphasis on squirrels and squirrel-adjacent creatures that possess no more than 9 Hit Dice is preferred.

Finally, I don't need the myriad of ways that a DM can *modify* squirrels with, for instance, [templates](http://dndsrd.net/monstersHtoI.html#half-dragon) or [spells](http://dndsrd.net/spellsAtoB.html#awaken)—I already know that such options exist and that I can use them. I'm looking only for standalone squirrels and squirrel-adjacent creatures.

Answer (score 2):

First, it's a homebrew class, so there is no source for an official ruling, but I believe you're misreading the class ability.

My interpretation is:

- You can turn into any kind of squirrel, but the creature/stats you adopt are all the same. Only your "look" would change. The "recognized by the DM" part I think just equates to "Oh you want to be a *Missouran Fox Squirrel*? Checks out, you're good to go; don't bang your tail on the way out."

  - There is no official "squirrel" creature. In that case I'd rule it inherits rat stats (http://dndsrd.net/monstersAnimal.html#rat) but if your DM is feeling kind there are homebrew squirrel stats.
- The description also dictates that if you want to move "beyond the box", you can apply templates to the squirrel creature such as "Dire", "Zombie", or "Undead".

There are mechanics for all those creatures (beyond the base squirrel class). I don't think the ability gives you carte blanche to just pick whatever homebrew/oddball creature you want to turn into :P

---

But, this aside, the goal is to have fun. If you want to go the more traditional route, I would replace the ability in whole with the Wererat's (https://www.dandwiki.com/wiki/SRD:Wererat) ability to turn into a bipedal Dire Rat. And then use the Dire Rat's stats. And then just "skin" it to be a squirrel. (https://www.dandwiki.com/wiki/SRD:Dire_Rat)

---

Actually, if you're not too far along you might just go the Wererat route and adopt that in it's entirety. Then you could have your race dictate the "squirrelness" and still adopt whatever class you want for play style. And then you're keeping within the SRD entirely, which is always a plus :)

Comment: I welcome the frame challenge. Thank you. (As an aside, changing the class feature so that the scarlet squirrel becomes an *actual* weresquirrel—while interesting—means adding 1 Hit Die of, essentially, animal to the character, which turns the whole shebang into a mechanical mess.)

Comment: Good point! Looks like an interesting class to play with :)